# Download pdf file from Java web app made in JSF

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

Hello I have a Java web app made in JSF...when you press a button it should write a string in a pdf file and download it. Here is the code:

```
String cont = "DATA CREARE: " + data_creare3 + "\n" + "CIF: " + cif3 + "\n" + "ID SOLICITARE: " + id_solicitare3 + "\n" + "DETALII" + detalii3 + "\n" + "TIP: " + tip3 + "\n" + "ID: " + id3;

startDownload(cont.getBytes(), "id.pdf");
```

This is the String and the method being called and here is the function that makes the download..

```
private void startDownload(byte[] continut, String denumire) throws IOException{
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    // externalContext.responseReset();
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Pragma", "public");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Length",
    Integer.toString(continut.length));
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + denumire + "\"");
    externalContext.getResponseOutputStream().write(continut);
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

When I click the button to download it says:

```
emptyResponse: An empty response was received from the server.  Check server error logs
```

The server error logs say:

```
2020-02-03 09:18:44,438 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-2) JSF1063: WARNING! Setting non-serializable attribute value into HttpSession (key: logic, value class: com.serban.Logic).
```

What should I do to make it work ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried the suggested anser and i get the same response...

Comment: Why do you think this simple String is a valid PDF document?

Comment: I`m converting it in bytes and giving it as a parameter to the function

Comment: You are sending that string to the web browser claiming it is a PDF which it is not. It does not match the [PDF file structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF#File_structure)