# Java web app trying trying to download info from API not working

Tags: jsf

I have a Java web app made in JSF that connects to a API fills a datatable with info and every row has download button. When I press download button it does another get request with an id taken from the row the button was clicked. But when I press the download button I get this message :

```
emptyResponse: An empty response was received from the server.  Check server error logs.
```

The server log doesn`t show any error.
This is the code:

```
package com.serban;

import com.google.common.io.ByteStreams;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.FontFactory;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

@ManagedBean(name = "logic", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class Logic implements Serializable {

static JSONObject jsonObject = null;
static JSONObject jo = null;
static JSONArray cat = null;

private ArrayList<Mesaj> logics;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String cif2;
String data_creare2;
String id_solicitare2;
String tip2;
String id2;
String detalii2;
String numar2;

/**
 *
 * @throws ParseException
 */

public void apelareApi()   {

  try {   
 URL url = new URL("xxx");
 URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
 String inputLine;

 while((inputLine = in.readLine())!= null){
     System.out.println(inputLine);
     sb.append(inputLine+"\n");


 }

 in.close();




 }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}



}



public void incarcareLista() throws ParseException  {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(sb.toString());
    cat = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("mesaje");
    logics = new ArrayList<Mesaj>();
        for(int i = 0; i < cat.size(); i++) {
    Mesaj m = new Mesaj();
    jo = (JSONObject) cat.get(i);
    cif2 = jo.get("cif").toString();
    data_creare2 = jo.get("data_creare").toString();
    id_solicitare2 = jo.get("id_solicitare").toString();
    tip2 = jo.get("tip").toString();
    id2 = jo.get("id").toString();
    detalii2 = jo.get("detalii").toString();
    numar2 = Integer.toString(i+1);
    m.setCif(cif2);
    m.setData_creare(data_creare2);
    m.setId_solicitare(id_solicitare2);
    m.setTip(tip2);
    m.setId(id2);
    m.setDetalii(detalii2);
    m.setNumar(numar2);
    logics.add(m);
}


}

/**
 *
 * @throws ParseException
 */
@PostConstruct
public void apelareSiIncarcare()  {
    apelareApi();
    try {
        incarcareLista();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Logic.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Mesaj> getLogics() {
    return logics;
}

public Logic() {
}

String x;
String id;
byte[] rasp;
public void printNumar(String x) throws IOException  {


    this.x = x;
    //System.out.println(x);


    int y = Integer.parseInt(x);
    jo = (JSONObject) cat.get(y-1);
    System.out.println(jo.get("id"));
    id = jo.get("id").toString();



    rasp = apelareApi2(id);

    startDownload(rasp);



    }
byte[] byteChunk;
public byte[] apelareApi2(String z) throws IOException {


        URL url = new URL("xxx"+z);

        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream is = null;
try {
is = url.openStream ();
byteChunk = new byte[is.available()]; // Or whatever size you want to read in at a time.
int n;

while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
   }
   }
  catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.printf ("Failed while reading bytes from %s: %s", url.toExternalForm(),e.getMessage());e.printStackTrace ();}finally {
  if (is != null) { is.close(); }
  }
 return byteChunk;
    }



private void startDownload(byte[] continut)
        throws IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    // externalContext.responseReset();
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Cache-Control", "public");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Pragma", "public");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Length",
            Integer.toString(continut.length));
    externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment;filename=\"" + "id.pdf" + "\"");
    externalContext.getResponseOutputStream().write(continut);
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}


}
```

Comment: It looks like you have added the PDF content part missing from [your coworker's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60034812/865107) question. But this is still not a [mcve], how does the minimal relevant UI part look like?

Comment: Please learn to break down problems... waay too much totally irrelevant code in here. If the remote call (from your code) fails, it is not JSF related. If that succeeds but JSF fails, it is not remote call related. Try to narrow that down and produce a [mcve] accordingly. That is what 'debugging' is all about.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is thrown by Mojarra JSF if an AJAX response is received which does not contain XML as [pointed out here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/33a5e61a7f466ffbcf8f61f8445006989bf65749/impl/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/javax.faces/jsf-uncompressed.js#L2703) and [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/33a5e61a7f466ffbcf8f61f8445006989bf65749/impl/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/javax.faces/jsf-uncompressed.js#L2016) in the `jsf-uncompressed.js`:

```
 * Receive an Ajax response 
 * from the server.
 * Usage:
 * 
 * jsf.ajax.response(request, context);
 * 
 * Implementation Requirements:
 * This function must evaluate the markup returned in the
 * request.responseXML object and perform the following action:
 * 
 * If there is no XML response returned, signal an "emptyResponse"
 * error.

 ...

 } else if (status == "emptyResponse") {
    data.description = "An empty response was received from the server.  Check server error logs.";
```

This shows you are using AJAX. As BalusC stated, JavaScript is not permitted to launch the **Save document** dialog here: [How to provide a file download from a JSF backing bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391838/how-to-provide-a-file-download-from-a-jsf-backing-bean/9394237#9394237)

So the solution bringing you one step closer is: turn off AJAX.